# Only getting items that are 2 months old or less in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table with a column called "creation_date_epoch" that is a type INT and gives me the creation date in epoch format. I want to retrieve all rows where the creation date is 2 months or less than the current date, but I don't know how to approach it. Could anyone help with this? Thank you in advanced!

Lets say we had this

```
{id: 1234, creation_date_epoch: 1651300805244}  
{id: 2345, creation_date_epoch: 1641017330836}  
{id: 3456, creation_date_epoch: 1539538644136}  
{id: 4567, creation_date_epoch: 1651340257517}  
{id: 5678, creation_date_epoch: 1651348676929}  
{id: 6789, creation_date_epoch: 1330850171000}
```

my goal is to return every row in which the creation date is 2 months old or younger, but I'm not sure how to approach it with the epoch values and all

Comment: Can you add sample code?

Comment: I just edited and added sample code!

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the functions:

`from_unixtime` - Where you can convert your timestamp to datetime or date. [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime.html)

`unix_timestamp` - To get the current date of your execution. [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp.html?highlight=unix_timestamp#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp)

`months_between` - To get a difference between the two dates and see how many months they are and apply a filter. [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.months_between.html?highlight=months_between#pyspark.sql.functions.months_between)

These are the three functions that you should apply and filter your data. Like

```
df.withColumn("creation_date", from_unixtime(col("creation_date_epoch"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  .withColumn("months_diff", months_between(unix_timestamp(None, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), col('creation_date')).where(col('months_diff') >= 2.0)
  .show()
```

Comment: thanks for the response! However I am getting a "Cannot resolve overloaded method 'unix_timestamp'" when I do .withColumn("months_diff", months_between(unix_timestamp(None, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), col('creation_date')).where(col('months_diff') >= 2.0). Any ideas on why?

Comment: it seems that unix_timestamp's parameters are incorrect and it expects a column as its first paramter?